# Browser is not launching when i run selenium webdriver

Tags: eclipse

I am new to selenium webdriver, I wrote a sample code to launch google when I run the script there are no errors I could see in console but browser is not launching. I use Testng to run in eclipse.

Please help me out.

Thanks,
Raghav

Answer (score 0):

Try to check options of different drivers.

The existing drivers are the [ChromeDriver](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver), [InternetExplorerDriver](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver), [FirefoxDriver](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver), [OperaDriver](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/OperaDriver) and [HtmlUnitDriver](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/HtmlUnitDriver). For more information about each of these, including their relative strengths and weaknesses, please follow the links to the relevant pages. There is also support for mobile testing via the [AndroidDriver](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AndroidDriver), OperaMobileDriver and IPhoneDriver.

For Chrome WebDriver you should start a server to be able to communicate with the browser.

Comment: Hi Arekkusandaa, everything was installed. I could figure out that there was a problem the way i was running in eclipse and also my browser zoom was set to 105% instead it should be 100%...... Thank you